# Problems with Laravel Pivot Table

Tags: laravel

I am working on a medical lab application in laravel where I have the following tables:
1. Test table: This is a table which stores all the information related to medical tests:
2: Checkup: This is a page which contains all the patient information along with the tests he/she takes.

This is the test page:
[image]

This is the Checkup page where the tests and their results are selected:
[image]

Here can be many tests and user can check any number of them and will write the result of the test in the textfield below the checkbox.
I get this data in the controller like below code and save it to the database:

```
$this->validate($request, 
    [

        'patient_name' => 'required|max:50',
        'patient_age' => 'required',
        'gender' => 'required',
        'patient_type' => 'required',
        'technition_id' => 'required',
        'result' => 'required',
        'test' => 'required',
        'amount' => 'required'


    ]);

    if( ($request->patient_type == 2) && ($request->doctor_id==0) )
    {
        return redirect()->back()->withInput(Input::all())->withErrors(['message' => 'Please select a valid Doctor.']);
    }

    $checkup = new Checkup;
    $checkup->patient_name = $request->patient_name;
    $checkup->patient_age = $request->patient_age;
    $checkup->gender = $request->gender;
    $checkup->patienttype_id = $request->patient_type;
    $checkup->technition_id = $request->technition_id;
    if(isset($request->doctor_id))
    {
        $checkup->doctor_id = $request->doctor_id;
    }
    $checkup->amount = $request->amount;
   // $checkup->result = $request->result;
    $checkup->save();

    $tests =[];
    $tests = $request->test;
    $results =[];
    $results = $request->result;

       //$checkup->tests()->attach($tests->id, ['result' => $result]);

       $sync_data = [];
        for($i = 0; $i < count($tests); $i++)
            $sync_data[$tests[$i]] = ['result' => $results[$i]];

        $checkup->tests()->sync($sync_data);




    Session::flash('success', 'The record was successfully saved.');

    return redirect()->route('checkups.index');
```

Now the problem is that when I check all the checkboxes and write the result of all the tests then it is fine but when I select some and leave some of them then it gives error and the error comes because the result textbox for the unchecked test is empty.

This is the case when I select one test and leave the others:

[image]

When I check on test and write the result of it and then var_dump both test and result arrays i get the below output:

[image]

In the above image we can see that the test array contains one item because only one checkbox was checked but the result array contains two items and the first one is NULL which belongs to the unchecked checkbox.

This is the view file of the checkboxes and the textfields:

```
{{ Form::label('tests', 'Tests Taken') }}

    @foreach(App\Test::all() as $test)

        <div class="checkbox checkbox-switchery">
            {{ Form::label('test', $test->name) }}
            <input name="test[]" value="{{ $test->id }}" type="checkbox" class="switchery-primary">

        </div>

        <div>
            {{ Form::label('result', "Result") }}
            <input name="result[]" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

    @endforeach

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('amount', 'Amount') }}
        {{ Form::text('amount', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::button('<i class="fa fa-save"> Save</i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-success'])}}

    </div>

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Please help me on this and show me how to insert the pivot table data properly to the system.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: please add view file code for the checkbox and textbox. Also it would be better to add code instead of images of code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I added the view file code. and it was very big question thats why I added photos.

Comment: Thanks for the attention and time. I added the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

In your blade file :

```
    @foreach(App\Test::all() as $index => $test)

        <div class="checkbox checkbox-switchery">
            {{ Form::label('test', $test->name) }}
            <input name="test[{{ $index }}]" value="{{ $test->id }}" type="checkbox" class="switchery-primary">

        </div>

        <div>
            {{ Form::label('result', "Result") }}
            <input name="result[{{ $index }}]" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>

    @endforeach
```

Instead of the `for` loop you can use `foreach` lopp.

```
    $sync_data = [];

    foreach($tests as $index => $value) {
        if(!empty($results[$index]) {
            $sync_data[$value] = ['result' => $results[$index]]
        }
    }

    $checkup->tests()->sync($sync_data);
```

Comment: It is not saving the sync data now.

Comment: The $sync_data is an empty array when one test is checked and one result is written, but when two tests are selected then one is stored in the table.

Comment: Yes, the `$tests` array contains the selected test id and the `$results` array contains two items, one NULL item for the unchecked test and one contains the written result for the checked test.

Comment: In your question, the `var_dump` result screenshot says the first checkbox is checked, and first result is null, and second checkbox is unchecked and second result has text, isn't it? are you trying with that option?

Comment: No, the first checkbox and first textfied for the result are left empty and the second test is checked and the result is also written for it.

Comment: It is still the same with selecting one test with one result, the `$sync_data` is empty.

Comment: Yes, the loop is iterating properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168949/discussion-between-ab-ab-and-abdul-raheem-ghani).